# if background equals issue

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement

I'm trying to apply an `if else statement` to an element determining whether another element has a particular background color.

I have stated the element background color as blue in the `CSS`, however when I add the javascript statement, the element ignores the background color stated in the `CSS` (blue) and adopts the one stated in the `JS IF statement` (red).

HTML:

```
<div id="img"></div>
<div id="color">test</div>
```

CSS;

```
#img {
    background:blue;
}
```

JS

```
if (document.getElementById('img').style.background = "red")
    {document.getElementById('color').style.background = "green";} 
else {document.getElementById('color').style.background = "red";}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/25c4Luaa/)

Comment: Instead of trying to fool the system and get around the rule of posting your code in your question when linking to jsFiddle, why not just do as you're asked to? If jsFiddle ever goes away or is inaccessible, your question loses all value to future visitors with your code in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is:

```
if (document.getElementById('img').style.background = "red")
```

You're actually resetting the CSS - not saying if it's equal to - try the following:

```
if (document.getElementById('img').style.background == "red")
{document.getElementById('color').style.background = "green";} 
else {document.getElementById('color').style.background = "red";}
```

The operator `==` is how you'd check if something is equal to something else, or you can use `===` if you want to make sure the type is also the same. A good explanation of the two operators can be found here: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/2932678)

Comment: That's great. Thanks for your help with that.

Comment: @GaryVoss no problem, glad I could help.